# How to install gems manually in heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm currently working on a polyglot microservice that uses both nodejs and ruby (originally it was only nodejs). i need to install some gems for ruby.

TL;DR

- gem install nokogiri => no directory permissions
- sudo gem install nokogiri => sudo command not found
- created Gemfile and bundle install => bundle command not found
- gem install bundler => same as above
- chown -R `whoami` /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 => Read-only file system
- chmod -R 777 ../var/lib/gems/2.3.0/ => no errors but still read only directory

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not manually maintain application dependencies via Heroku CLI.

When you deploy to Heroku, assuming you have picked 'Ruby' or 'Rails' as the Heroku application type, the buildpack it will bundle for you. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#deploy-the-app
You can find your app type and build pack here:
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/HEROKU_APP_NAME/settings

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path
```

You should also know that Heroku Dynos are ephemeral. You do not have a dedicated server where you can SSH in and make file / permission changes that persist. Anytime your dyno resets or you push new code to production, your entire file system is 'regenerated' from git.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said, i had to add ruby in the Buildpacks here: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/HEROKU_APP_NAME/settings, also i had to add a Gemfile and a Gemfile.lock to the project